# Application prompts me to install JRE higher than 1.4, but I have 1.7 installed

Tags: windows-xp, java, jre

There is a JRE 1.7 on my Windows XP machine. The `java -version` command says that  I have `1.7.0_02`.

By launching an `.exe` file, I want to install an internet banking software that uses Java, but it said that I have to install a JRE higher than 1.4.

I've also tried to run that program with JRE 1.6 (which is also installed on my machine), but the error is still the same.

Comment: It sounds like this particular program's JRE version detection may be broken.

Comment: Tell your bank that it's [no use pretending that the economic crisis hasn't happened](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#J2SE_1.4_.28February_6.2C_2002.29) and that they need to join us in the future.

Comment: Hmm.., what do you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are right ways to detect program versions and there are wrong ways.

Especially with Java, there may be requirements that not only a "higher than" version be present, but sometimes even a very, very specific version and higher versions won't work any better than lower versions.

This program appears to be using either the wrong method of determining version, or it uses the right version and then uses the wrong words to communicate what it really wants.

The fix is to either install Java version 1.4 (not recommended, there have been a lot of critical security holes patched since then) or tell your bank that you need a new version of the software that doesn't have such gaping security issues.